# Solve a forced system of differential equations with Mathematica (with Heaviside)

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems

It is my first time here so I hope this question fits here.
I want to solve the following system of equations:

$x1'[t] == Vpv/L1 - x3[t]/L1*(1-u(t))$

$x2'[t] == x3[t]/L1*u(t) - x4[t]/L2$

$x3'[t] == x1[t]/C1*(1 - u(t)) - x2[t]/C1*u(t)$

$x4'[t] == x2[t]/C2 - x[4]/(R*C2)$

The system above models an electric circuit and C1,C2,L1,L2,Vpv are given parameters. $u(t)= 0.553- 0.1*\Theta[t - 30*10^{-3}] + 0.2*\Theta[t - 120*10^{-3}];$ With $\Theta(t)$ The heaviside function.

I tried to solve this in Mathematica but I wasn't unable to solve it  with neither DSolve nor NDSolve. Mathematica just returns no answer.

The code is:

```
R = 12;

C1 = 250*10^(-6);

C2 = 250*10^(-6);

L1 = 20*10^(-3);

L2 = 20*10^(-3);

uo = 0.553;

Vpv = 40;

u[t_] = uo - 0.1*UnitStep[t - 30*10^(-3)] + 
   0.2*UnitStep[t - 120*10^(-3)];

DSolve[{x1'[t] == Vpv/L1 - x3[t]/L1*(1 - u[t]), 
  x2'[t] == x3[t]/L1*(u[t]) - x4[t]/L2,
  x3'[t] == x1[t]/C1*(1 - u[t]) - x2[t]/C1*u[t], 
  x4'[t] == x2[t]/C2 - x[4]/(R*C2), x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, 
  x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 0}, {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}, t]
```

And when I try to use NDSolve, M just says "non-numerical value found". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

Whenever you are getting the above error message, there are high chances that you have used incorrect syntax, like in your case `x[4]` which should be `x4[t]`, or maybe some numerical values are missing for some parameter.

```
R = 12; C1 = 250*10^(-6); C2 = 250*10^(-6); L1 = 20*10^(-3); L2 = 
 20*10^(-3); uo = 0.553; Vpv = 40;

u[t] = uo - 0.1*UnitStep[t - 30*10^(-3)] +  0.2*UnitStep[t - 120*10^(-3)];

eq1 = x1'[t] == Vpv/L1 - x3[t]/L1*(1 - u[t]);

eq2 = x2'[t] == x3[t]/L1*(u[t]) - x4[t]/L2;

eq3 = x3'[t] == x1[t]/C1*(1 - u[t]) - x2[t]/C1*u[t];

eq4 = x4'[t] == x2[t]/C2 - x4[t]/(R*C2);

sol = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0, x3[0] == 0, x4[0] == 0}, 
{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]}, {t, 0, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue, Black}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oops. didn't see that. My bad, thanks! By the way, why did you use "Rationalize" for uo?

Comment: @MiguelDuranDiaz You don't need Rationalize here, since we are using numerical method to solve ur odes.